# Calculating future investment amount in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, finance

I'm trying to calculate the future investment amount in Java. 
My program runs, but it's not giving me the correct answer.

If the

- investmentAmount is      1000.56,
- interest rate is         4.25, and
- number of years is       1,
- the answer should be     $1043.92.

The formula we have to use is `futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate) ^ numberOfYears * 12`

Below is my class

```
// Import Java Scanner
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex_2_21 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create a Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt the user to enter investment amount, annual interest rate, and number of years
        System.out.println("Enter investment amount:");
        System.out.println("Enter annual interest rate:");
        System.out.println("Enter number of years:");
        float investmentamount = input.nextFloat();
        float interestrate = input.nextFloat();
        float numberofyears = input.nextFloat();
        float years = numberofyears * 12;

        //Formula to calculate the accumulated value

        float futureInvestmentValue = (float) (investmentamount * Math.pow((years), 1 + interestrate));

        //Print result
        System.out.println("The accumulated value is " + futureInvestmentValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using years (equal to years * 12) when you mean months, and you're not using monthly interest rate at all. Divide annual interest rate (as entered) by 12 to get monthly interest rate (and also make sure it's a fraction, not a bare percentage, so if they're entering 4.25 it needs to be divided by 100 to get .0425), and introduce a new variable for total month duration. Then (as Luiggi notes) swap the argument order.

```
float futureInvestmentValue = (float) (investmentAmount * Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, months));
```

Comment: @JY: If an answer works for you, you should probably hit that little checkmark over there. ;)

Answer (score 1):

On top of what @Luiggi said, did you consider that if it is 4.25 interest rate, that is 425% interest rate, what you want is 1 + 0.0425

Comment: Yeah the interest rate should be in percentages. I did enter 0.0425 as the interest rate and it did give me the correct answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
Math.pow((years), 1 + interestrate)
```

It should be

```
Math.pow(1 + interestrate, years)
```

As noted in [`Math#pow(double a, double b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-):

> **Parameters:**
> `a` - the base
> `b` - the exponent
>
> **Returns**
> The value a<sup>b</sup>

Comment: Thank you Luiggi. I've changed the code to what you have suggested and it did get me closer to the correct answer, but it still giving me the incorrect answer. This is very helpful.

Comment: Probably *it doesn't work* because you're working with floating points directly, which can give odd results. It will be better to use `BigDecimal` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the above given Java program:

1. Lack of problem understanding (kindly, take this suggestion in a positive interest. If we, understand the problem correctly, we are very much near to its correct programming solution.)

Formula for future investment value (A) is as follows:

a) Compounded annually:

A = P*(1+R)^N

Where, A = Future value, P = Original amount invested, R = Interest rate (given as %, in calculation use as R/100), N = Time period for which compound interest rate is applied (in years)

b) Compounded monthly:

A = P*(1+(R/12))^(N*12)

Where, A = Future value, P = Original amount invested, R = Monthly interest rate (given as %, in calculation use as R/100, it is not annual interest rate), N = Time period for which compound interest rate is applied (in years)

As per values of given sample problem, we find in order to calculate future investment value, we should be using formula (b).

So, w.r.t above given Java program, to incorporate this correction we need to simply add one more statement after the interestrate variable declaration line:

interestrate = interestrate / (100 * 12);

2. Second problem is lack of understanding of Java programming language constructs / logical error by ignorance. Whatever is the case; it does not matter. Technically, it is a programming error and thus it needs rectification.

As already suggested above by Luiggi Mendoza, in Java programming language if we want to express mathematical expression A^B then we have to use  java.lang.Math.pow() method with following syntax:

public static double pow(double A, double B)

So, again w.r.t above given Java program, to incorporate this second correction we have to simply correct the line which declares the futureInvestmentValue variable and using the Math.pow() method; as follows:

float futureInvestmentValue = (float) (investmentamount * Math.pow(1 + interestrate, years));

Incorporating these two corrections, we make our solution correct. Based on the principle of GIGO (Garbage In Garbage Out, Gold In Gold Out) we will definitely get correct and exact answer to our any sample problem given values; as expected.

Happy Programming.